# Click-Circle game - clicking outside and inside the circle

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code a game that has a red circle in which the user is supposed to click up to 7 times in the window. If the user clicks outside the circle, the circle will change its position to where the user clicked. And the game should end when the user has clicked 3 times inside the circle (does not have to be in a row) or when the user has clicked 7 times in total.
I have coded and done quite most of it I think, its just I cant seem to make it work as I want to.

```
from graphics import *

def draw_circle(win, c=None):

    x = random.randint(0,500)
    y = random.randint(0,500)

    if var is None:
        centa = Point(x,y)
        var = Circle(centa,50)
        var.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
        var.draw(win)
    else:
        p1 = c.p1
        x_dif = (p1.x - x) * -1
        y_dif = (p1.y - y) * -1
        var.move(x_dif, y_dif)
    return (var, x, y)

def main():
    win= GraphWin("game",800,800)
    score = 0
    var,x,y = draw_circle(win)
    while score <= 7:
        mouseClick2=win.getMouse()
        if mouseClick2.y >= y-50 and mouseClick2.y <= y +50 and 
mouseClick2.x >= x-50 and mouseClick2.x <= x+50:
            score=score + random.randint(0,5)
        var,x,y = draw_circle(win, c)

    print ("Success!")
    print (("the score is, {0}").format(score))
```

thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Is there any other problem besides checkbox being a square?

Comment: I didnt quite understand what you meant with the checkbox being square?

Comment: I meant hitbox, sorry, my mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a python guy, but I see that your hitbox is wrong. If there are any other issues then comment it/them to me.

**Solving hitbox to be circle:**

What you have already written is good to have thing but you should check if click was in circle not square. Pythagoras triangle is solution for this.
Check:

```
if (math.sqrt(delta_x **2 + delta_y **2) <= circle_radius)
```

where delta_x and delta_y is center coordinate minus mouse position

Comment: I agree that the Pythagorean formula could be useful here. Take care, though: Python's exponentiation operator is `**`, not `^`. Or you could just use `math.hypot`.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for pointing out. I haven't really used Python much so I don't really know syntax (also I was almost sure ^ is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple problems.

- your `if mouseClick2.y >= y-50...` conditional is spread out on two lines, but you don't have a line continuation character.
- You never call `main()`.
- You don't import `random`.
- You call `draw_circle` in the `while` loop with an argument of `c`, but there is no variable by that name in the global scope. You probably meant to pass in `var`.
- `c` in `draw_circle` ostensibly refers to the circle object you want to manipulate, but half the time you manipulate `var` instead of `c`.
- you assign a value to `cvar` in the loop, but never use it.
- Your `else` block in `draw_circle` calculates the movement delta by subtracting the cursor coordinates from c.p1. But c.p1 is the upper-left corner of the circle, not the center of the circle. So your hit detection is off by fifty pixels.

```
import random
from graphics import *

def draw_circle(win, c=None):

    x = random.randint(0,500)
    y = random.randint(0,500)

    if c is None:
        centa = Point(x,y)
        c = Circle(centa,50)
        c.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
        c.draw(win)
    else:
        center_x = c.p1.x + 50
        center_y = c.p1.y + 50
        x_dif = (center_x - x) * -1
        y_dif = (center_y - y) * -1
        c.move(x_dif, y_dif)
    return (c, x, y)

def main():
    win= GraphWin("game",800,800)
    score = 0
    var,x,y = draw_circle(win)
    while score <= 7:
        mouseClick2=win.getMouse()
        if mouseClick2.y >= y-50 and mouseClick2.y <= y +50 and \
mouseClick2.x >= x-50 and mouseClick2.x <= x+50:
            score=score + random.randint(0,5)
        var,x,y = draw_circle(win, var)

    print ("Success!")
    print (("the score is, {0}").format(score))

main()
```

Additional possible improvements:

- Your hit detection checks whether the cursor is in a 50x50 rectangle centered on the circle. You could instead check whether the cursor is inside the circle if you measured the distance between the cursor and the center, and checked whether it was less than the radius.
- `var` and `c` could stand to have more descriptive names.
- `mouseClick2` doesn't make much sense as a name, considering there's no `mouseClick1`.
- The movement delta arithmetic could be simplified: `(a-b) * -1` is the same as `(b-a)`.
- If you only use a variable's value once, you can sometimes avoid creating the variable at all if you nest expressions.
- it might be nice to define constants, such as for the circle's radius, instead of having magic numbers in your code.
- You can save five characters by using `+=` to increment the score.

```
import math
import random
from graphics import *

RADIUS = 50

def draw_circle(win, circle=None):

    x = random.randint(0,500)
    y = random.randint(0,500)

    if circle is None:
        circle = Circle(Point(x,y),RADIUS)
        circle.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
        circle.draw(win)
    else:
        circle.move(
            x - circle.p1.x - RADIUS, 
            y - circle.p1.y - RADIUS
        )
    return (circle, x, y)

def main():
    win= GraphWin("game",800,800)
    score = 0
    circle,x,y = draw_circle(win)
    while score <= 7:
        cursor = win.getMouse()
        if math.hypot(cursor.x - x, cursor.y - y) <= RADIUS:
            score += random.randint(0,5)
        circle,x,y = draw_circle(win, circle)

    print ("Success!")
    print (("the score is, {0}").format(score))

main()
```

Comment: I tried your correction, the problem is it still doesnt stop/ terminate after 3 clicks inside the circle. And if I click outside it, it doesnt have a limit to stop

Comment: Right, it doesn't terminate at three clicks, because it keeps going until the score is greater than 7, and any successful click can give you as little as zero points. If you want the loop to terminate after some number of failures, you could have a `misses` variable that you increment within the loop, and change the loop condition to `while score <= 7 and misses < 3:`